# Multiple match between boundaries

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do a multiple match within a string but I just need to find the matches between some boundaries.

EX: Let's say I have the following string and flags inside the string. I just need to find the '*123.12*' that are between the HELLO and BYE flags.

Lorem Ipsum is *123.12* dummy text of the printing and *123.12* industry. *123.12* Ipsum has been the industry's *123.12* dummy text ever *123.12* the 1500s, when an unknown *123.12* took a galley of *123.12* and scrambled it to *123.12* a type specimen *123.12*. HELLO *123.12* has survived not only *123.12* centuries, *123.12* also the leap into *123.12* typesetting, remaining *123.12* unchanged. BYE It was *123.12* in *123.12* 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software *123.12* Aldus PageMaker *123.12* versions of *123.12* Ipsum.

[image: This is an example of what I'm doing]

Right now I'm doing a match with all the substrings that have the characteristics I need but it is matching outside the range I need.

PS: The engine is python and no libraries can be added.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I see. Are there more than 1 items between HELLO and BYE that you want to match ?

Comment: What is this `(?<=PRICE)?((?:\s*-\$\#@\$-\s*\$\s*)(\d[\d\.\,]+)(?=TOTAL)\s[a-zA=Z]{3})?` supposed to be doing ? Can you link to your regex101 sample instead of a screenshot of it ?

Comment: Anyway the short answer is you could use the \G anchor, but you'd have to install the _regex_ module `import regex`. Otherwise you have to do it in 2 steps. Capture all between HELLO(.+?)BYE. then run the inner regex to find the individual decimal's you seek. Thats your only 2 options.

Comment: As @Maxt8r mentioned, you'll need to include properly-formatted text containing your regex (and any other text-based content), not an image. Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) which provides many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score -1):

```
string = """Lorem Ipsum is *123.12* dummy text of the printing and *123.12* industry. *123.12* Ipsum has been the industry's *123.12* dummy text ever *123.12* the 1500s, when an unknown *123.12* took a galley of *123.12* and scrambled it to *123.12* a type specimen *123.12*. HELLO *123.12* has survived not only *123.12* centuries, *123.12* also the leap into *123.12* typesetting, remaining *123.12* unchanged. BYE It was *123.12* in *123.12* 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software *123.12* Aldus PageMaker *123.12* versions of *123.12* Ipsum."""

startFlag = 'HELLO'
endFlag = 'BYE'

lookingFor = '*123.12*'

EndOfStartFlagIndex = string.index(startFlag) + len(startFlag)

betweenFlags = string.split(startFlag)[1].split(endFlag)[0]

lookingForInices = [i+EndOfStartFlagIndex for i in range(0,len(betweenFlags)) if betweenFlags[i:i+len(lookingFor)] == lookingFor]

print(lookingForInices)
```